# Use proven constructions to derive a DFSA.

Tags: formal-languages, geometric-construction

$$ M1 = < \{A,B,C\}, \{a\}, \{(A, a)\} \to B, (A, a) \to C\}, A, \{B\} >$$

Assume that $T(M1) = {a}$. Use proven constructions to derive a DFSA, $M2$, from $M1$ such that $T(M2) = T(M1)$.

My thought about it is it will be the following:
$$ M2 = < \{A,B\}, \{a\}, \{(A, a)\} \to B\}, A, \{B\} > $$

i.e. C isn't included since it is not a final state, it will be a state which if is reached the system would crash. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Hmm, what is "geometric" about this?

Comment: You'll need to explain what each of the elements of your $M_1$ tuple are. Different authors specify automata with slightly different details in the formalism, and there is no universal standard for what goes in which order. And _in particular_ if you want to use only "proven" constructions, you're apparently expecting us to _guess_ which constructions you have proved ...

Comment: Your problem states "use proven constructions." We have no idea what constructions have been proven to you. Your $M_2$ is indeed a DFSA equivalent to the Turing Machine $M_1$. And if you include $C$ and the corresponding transition, then the rsulting FSA is not deterministic.  So probably you have to apply some constructions converting a TM to a FSA and after that you have to apply a construction to determinize the resulting FSA. The result will probably look very much like your $M_2$.